# swift4 UISwipeGestureRecognizer Viewcontroller with large title and cells not working

Tags: swift4, cell, uisearchbar, uiswipegesturerecognizer, large-title

I have a `ViewController` with large titles. In my `ViewController` are 2 cells. `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` is not working by swiping down. I want to call a `searchController` with this swipe-action in the titleView. Could the reason be the large title ?( with swipe down the title goes down and becomes greater, thats OK ). But **my** swipe action will not be recognized.  Any ideas?

[image]

my code: - function called in `viewDidLoad()` in ViewController

```
    func swipeSetup() {

    let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(funcSwipedDown(sender:)))
    swipeDown.direction = .down

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

}

@objc func funcSwipedDown(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){

    Utils.displayAlert(title: "Info", message: "swipe down")

    self.addNavigationbar() // func for adding search bar
}
```

Comment: I think once try with scrollViewDIdscroll method and you can manage with tableview height !!

Comment: When you set the cells in the `cellForRow` method, try setting `cell.userInteractionEnabled = false`. Right now it can be that the event is going to the cell and not to the gesture recogniser.

Comment: THX i will try this. But scrolling should work further.